# Why is this ForEach loop so slow

Tags: powershell, performance, for-loop

I have list of directory strings (millions) that need to be shorten to meet a specific length (MaxPathLength), once I remove the extra characters I need to either add them to another array list or a file.
It is important that I do not modify the top 2 level directory names, hence the `$topLevel = "{0}\{1}\{2}" -f $SubDir.Split("\")`. Moving this part outside the loop is not possible as there are 10s of thousands top 2 level directories.

I tried both using the NewPathList (long strings) array to pipe to the ForEach and reading from the the file and both are painfully slow.
8-9 minutes for 15,0000 directories.

I also tried the ForEach-Object -parallel doing the appropriate modifications, and it is also painfully slow.

```
  $NewPathList | Foreach {$SubDir = $_
  [int]$Chars2Remove  = $SubDir.length - $MaxPathLength
  If (($SubDir.Length -gt $MaxPathLength))
  {
      [string]$TopLevel           = "{0}\{1}\{2}" -f $SubDir.Split("\")
      [string]$Path2Shorten       = $null
      [string]$Path2Shorten       = $SubDir -replace([regex]::Escape($TopLevel))
      For($c=1;$c -le $Chars2Remove;$c++)
          {
              $MostRecurringChar     = ($Path2Shorten.GetEnumerator() | Group-Object -NoElement| Sort-Object count -Descending | Select-Object -First 1).Name
              $RandIndex = ([regex]::matches($Path2Shorten,'[.$MostRecurringChar]').index | Select-Object -Last 1) # | Get-Random -Count 1
              $ShortString = $Path2Shorten.Remove($RandIndex,1)
          }

          [String]$SubDir2Create      = $TopLevel  + $ShortString
  }
  else {
      [String]$SubDir2Create      = $null
      [String]$SubDir2Create      = $SubDir.ToString()
  }

  $ShortPathList.Add($SubDir2Create)
```

}

Comment: Your loop within a loop is what's taking so long. Just use `.Substring()`

Comment: It would propably be easier to understand the problem if you'd give examples of input and expected output.

Comment: Directory searches take long time when you have links in the directory that create loops.  You may want to run code on only subfolders and see which ones take long time to find the loops.

Comment: @jdweng, it is not a directory search. As I mentioned in the problem statement the directory strings are in a text file, even if I read the file to an array newpathlist the  "shortening" loop  of the directory string is what takes time.

Comment: Is issue reading the file, processing the file. or maybe the memory. Monitor using Task Manager the memory and try just reading file.  Then again doing processing and compare times.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Substring()` instead of looping through the characters:

```
$NewPathList | foreach {
    $SubDir = $_
    [int]$Chars2Remove  = $SubDir.length - $MaxPathLength
    if ($SubDir.Length -gt $MaxPathLength){
        [string]$TopLevel = "{0}\{1}\{2}" -f $SubDir.Split("\")
        [string]$Path2Shorten       = $null
        [string]$Path2Shorten       = $SubDir -replace([regex]::Escape($TopLevel))
        [int]$RemainingLength = $MaxPathLength - $TopLevel.Length
        $ShortString = $Path2Shorten.Substring(($Path2Shorten.Length - $RemainingLength))
        [String]$SubDir2Create = $TopLevel + $ShortString
    }
} else {
    [String]$SubDir2Create      = $null
    [String]$SubDir2Create      = $SubDir.ToString()
}
$ShortPathList.Add($SubDir2Create)
```

Comment: Thank you, however the problem here is that substring() removes any character regardless a given character recurrence, and could remove an entire directory. For example lets say that '($Path2Shorten.Length - $RemainingLength)' equals 10 and the directory structure is \123\456\789\10-11-12

Comment: @Gt3pccb your question isn't clear as to which characters you want to remove. From your code, it appears you're getting the most common characters and picking one at random to remove. As someone asked above: what exactly is the output you want to be returned?

Comment: This is an example:  the long directory is **e:\!Data\Getjygnz4ltnxyStorageTierSupportedSize\Renamewkcmi43zndvNetIPsecMainModeCryptoSet\Getlsrjzzrga4iSmbBandWidthLimit\Getydv0z4gdzooVpnConnection\Remove3yhecpyq5iqNetIPHttpsCertBinding\Getvw5obtc3anpDscResource**  
Short directory is **e:\!Data\Getjygnz4ltnxyStorageTierSuppotedSize\enmewkcmi43zndvNtIPecMainModeCryptoSet\Getlrjzzrg4SmbBandWidthLimit\Geydv0z4gdzooVpnonnectin\Remove3yhecpyq5iqNetIPHttpCertBindig\Getvw5obtc3anpDsResoure**  The point is to remove the characters randomly based on character recurrence.

Comment: until the directory string meets the directory string max length, without changing the depth.

Comment: @Gt3pccb you could try splitting the path (`$Path2Shorten.Split('\')`) then trim the last 1, 2, however many characters from all directories: 
`$Path2Shorten.Split('\') | % { $_.substring(0, ($_.Length - 2)) }`

Comment: @jjerdub1993, the substring route when you add all the checks and loops is even slower, because it is not safe to assume that you can remove "X" number of characters from each directory name. I would need the length of each split, then select the longest and remove some "n" number of characters, then compare the new directory name to the others, select the longest and repeat until the entire string, including the "\", met the required length.